# Angular 4 renderer2 setStyle not working

Tags: angular

in a component, im attempting to target a dom node and change it's style but this does not work, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

```
@Input() progress:number = 0;

...

ngOnChanges() {
    this.progressInnerEl = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.progress-inner');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.progressInnerEl, 'width', this.progress+'%');
  }
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
   @HostListener('focus') onFocus() {
    this._renderer.setStyle(this._el.nativeElement, 'width', '200px');
```

BTW Renderer is deprecated, so `Renderer.setElementStyle` was changed to `Renderer2.setStyle`.

Comment: Would be better to setStyle in the constructor or in the ngOnInit method than whenever the element gets focus.